# How can I disable redis master-slave replication with Sentinel

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-sentinel

We have an application with Redis Sentinel(3 sentinel 1 master 1 slave). We don't need replication at all. How can I turn off replication?

Answer (score 5):

The command [SLAVEOF NO ONE](http://redis.io/commands/slaveof), when sent to a slave, will turn off the replication. The slave will become a master.

If you disable replication, you probably don't need Redis Sentinel either.